# How can I group steps in Kettle/Spoon?

Tags: grouping, kettle

My Kettle/Spoon (4.1.0) transformation is getting pretty large, it has 30 steps so far. It is using 7 data sources and will produce about 5 outputs. I want to enclose parts of the graph into single steps. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the sub mapping step

This allows you to define a new transform, with a "mapping input" and one or more "mapping output" steps. you then put a sub mapping into the parent transform in the place where all your other steps have been moved to the child transform.

I use these from time to time - they're great as they allow "code" reuse.  It's also handy that you can have multple outputs - e.g. for outputting data at different levels of aggregation so you only have to aggregate it in one place.

PS: How come you're not on PDI4.2 yet?

Comment: I will try it soon. About PS: Coincidence. Download in progress :-)